# Need help with a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a payments table that has the following structure.

```
**Payments**
id
name
created_by - user_id
closed_by - user_id

**Users**
user_id
name
surname
```

What is the best way to show both the name and surname of the user who has created and closed the payment file.

The only way i can think this could work would be using a subquery for both(created_by,closed_by fields) thanks

Comment: Can you give me an example of the `JOIN` would look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 
CONCAT (u1.name,' ', u1.surname) created,
CONCAT (u2.name,' ', u2.surname) closed,
FROM payments p INNER JOIN users u1
ON p.created_by = u1.user_id
INNER JOIN users u2
ON p.closed_by = u2.user_id
```

**EDITED:**  if you want name and surname splitted

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, 
u1.name created_name, u1.surname created_surname,
u2.name closed_name, u2.surname closed_surname,
FROM payments p INNER JOIN users u1
ON p.created_by = u1.user_id
INNER JOIN users u2
ON p.closed_by = u2.user_id
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand i have created_by and closed_by witch are essentially a `user_id` but i need both name and surname for the created_by and closed by fields

Comment: @Contra: I gave you joined fields... if you want them splitted, I gonna edit my post...

Comment: Legend this works i will thanks will accept stackoverflow allows me(3 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

A strict join is **not** enough, I think you can use joins in the where clause

```
select name, surname
from 
    payments p, users u
where
    u.user_id = p.created_by
    and u.user_id = p.closed_by
```

Comment: `payments` does not have a column `user_id`.

Comment: I think this doesn't work if created_by is different from closed_by. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Marco as far as I know @Contra writes "who has created and closed the payment file." so it should not actually work

Answer (score 0):

You can join to a single table multiple times, but you have to use an alias.

```
select
p.*,cr.*,cl.*
from
payments p
join users cr
on p.created_by = cr.user_id
join users cl
on p.closed_by = cl.user_id
```